# How to say "plunge into (studies)"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Please, could you help me to translate the phrase in bold in the following sentence?

> I have **plunged into** my studies.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

> 勉強[漬]{づ}けだ
>   [I'm] immersed in [my] study

Comment: A little addition not directly answering the question but 一夜漬け means work all night hoping that the upcoming test will go well.

Answer (score 1):

勉強にハマっている is one option.

〜にハマる is a construction that is used to say that you're really into something, which I think is the gist of what one means when they say that they've "plunged into" something.